# How to understand/use gl-matrix function fromRotationTranslationScale()

Tags: animation, matrix, gl-matrix

I have a cube in GL in this [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/Ezk9iSfl6edKjCPEEsbC?p=preview) that looks like this:
[image]

I would like to scale, rotate and translate the cube from a pivot. 
to hopefully make it animate like https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sZeBm8EM3mw&feature=youtu.be

For this transformation I'll be using:
[gl-matrix](http://glmatrix.net/docs/module-mat4.html).  luckily this transformation has a method for this under `mat4.fromRotationTranslationScale()`

Problem is I'm have a hell of a time just using the method?  No errors, just the default implementation removed the cube from the screen.

```
mat4.fromRotationTranslationScale(
  matrix,
  quat.create(), 
  vec3.create(),
  vec3.create()
);
```

> (static) `fromRotationTranslationScale(out, q, v, s) → {mat4}`
>
> Creates a matrix from a quaternion rotation, vector translation and vector scale.

```
Parameters:

Name    Type    Description
out mat4    mat4 receiving operation result
q   quat4   Rotation quaternion
v   vec3    Translation vector
s   vec3    Scaling vector
```

### **Question:**

**Am I using `fromRotationTranslationScale` incorrectly? If so, where am I going wrong.  if not, how can get some kind of feedback to play around with.**

I'm weak with the math but I feel like I can reverse engineer and learn with your help ;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your problem is the scale vector. Indeed, I suppose the default vector values are `0.0`,`0.0`,`0.0` and if you put this scale parameter into the transformation, your object disapear since it have a size of `0.0`... and, 0 is too small to be visible :)

The good idententy values to pass to this kind of function are the following:

```
//             X    Y    Z    W
Quaternion  =  0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0
Translation =  0.0, 0.0, 0.0
Scale       =  1.0, 1.0, 1.0
```

This corresponds to the identity matrix:

```
 1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0
```

You can notice the diagonal of `1.0`, if you put scale values to `0.0` this diagonal becomes filled by `0.0`, then all vectors (vertices positions for example) transformed by this matrix are multiplied on all axis by `0.0`, which gives `0.0` everywhere.

Comment: I can make a whole new question but would you have any idea(libraries) that would help to interpolate over a starting matrix to final matrix value from mat4.fromRotationTranslationScale(x,y,z,w) inside my draw() requestAnimationFrame()?

Comment: i could give you answere on how to achieve correcte animation interpolation using quaternion/matrix, but independenttly from any "library". I know how to do and what to do, but not "which" library does it (except mine, which is not even in beta status). I can begin by giving you a clue for quaternions: searchs "SLERP" and "Fast SLERP" in google

Comment: http://glmatrix.net/docs/quat.js.html#line585 ayeeeee I think your clue clue is helping!!!

Comment: Yep, that's what you need. However be carefull, this `sqlerp` function take 2 "control points" in addition comparing the more traditionnal (and usually sufficient) slerp. Begin with what is at the line 217, way sufficient I think.

Comment: This would only handle rotation of my transformation right? http://glmatrix.net/docs/vec3.js.html#line452 this could handle the others yeah?

Comment: As i edited before, i suggest you to begin with simple linear interpolation `slerp`, you'll have all the time to explore bézier curves after...

Comment: and yes, this will only peforms rotation interpolation, you have to interpolate translation and scale in parallel. And in case you ask for:  `interpolation = BeginValue+T*(EndValue-BeginValue)` where `T` is from 0 to 1. You can use this for each x, y and z of translation and scale.